# Backbone undefined although referenced

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I have an app-module to load a router. The app defines the dependencies to the modules I need and puts them into its anonymous function. Inside this function the router is beeing initialized.
If the router-module also defines the dependency to Backbone and puts it into its anonymous function, Backbone is not available inside the router-module. 
How come?

The error:

[image]

Here is the boot-order:

[image]

This is my app:

```
require.config({
paths: {
    jquery: 'jquery',
    underscore: 'underscore',
    backbone: 'backbone',
    mustache: 'mustache',
    router: 'router'
},
shim: {
    'underscore': ['jquery'],
    'backbone': ['underscore'],
    'router' : ['backbone'],
    'mustache': ['backbone']   } 
});

 define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'mustache',
'router'
],
function($, _, Backbone, Mustache, Router) {
var initialize = function(){
    console.log("app initialized");
    Router.initialize();
};
return { initialize: initialize};
});
```

my Router with defines:

```
define([
'jquery', 
'underscore',
'backbone',
'view'
],
function ($,_,Backbone,View) {

console.log("Router defined");

var initialize = function () {
    console.log("router initialized");
    //Doing stuff on Backbone
};
return { initialize: initialize };
});
```

If I drop the reference to Backbone inside the router-module I can work with it.

Edit:

Here's the main-file:

```
require([
   'app',
], function(App){
   App.initialize();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from log, your app is defined earlier that Router. There is a mistake in your `main.js`, you should not use `define()`, but instead use `require()` function.

```
require.config({
paths: {
    jquery: 'jquery',
    underscore: 'underscore',
    backbone: 'backbone',
    mustache: 'mustache',
    router: 'router'
},
shim: {
    'underscore': ['jquery'],
    'backbone': ['underscore'],
    'router' : ['backbone'],
    'mustache': ['backbone']   } 
});

 require([
'router'
],
function(Router) {
    console.log("app initialized");
    Router.initialize();
});
```

Comment: If I use require, the main.js says App is undefined. 
I added my main.js above in my question.

Comment: is your app and main.js files are in same folder?

Comment: Yes, I put all files into the same folder. Not to have any trouble with wrong filepaths. I'll change that when the basic things work :)